# How to implement a layer above a layout?

Tags: android

How to implement a layer above a layout? like this pic:
http://ss12.sinaimg.cn/orignal/5d8cb30ag8f47eca43a5b&690

Comment: use a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout)

Answer (score 3):

I guess this link will help you a lot. It shows examples on how to implement the [Quick Actions pattern](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) and also the kind of menus you requested which btw are also used in the Google Gallery app.

Here's the link:  http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: hi,Juri,Your reply is very important to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To create that kind of floating menu I think [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) would be what you are looking for.